# Writing an SQL trigger to compare old and new values

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

I am trying to write a SQL trigger that compares the old and new values. If the two values are different then I need to display an error saying that you can't update the names. The exact definition of my trigger is

> write a trigger function named disallow_team_name_update that compares
>   the OLD and NEW records  team fields. If they are different raise an
>   exception that states that changing the team name is  not allowed.
>   Then, attach this trigger to the table with the name tr disallow team
>   name update  and specify that it fires before any potential update of
>   the team field in the table.

The table that I am using for this problem is:

```
  Table "table.group_standings"
    Column |         Type          | Modifiers
   --------+-----------------------+-----------
    team   | character varying(25) | not null
    wins   | smallint | not null   
    losses | smallint | not null
    draws  | smallint | not null
    points | smallint| not null
   Indexes:
     "group_standings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (team)
  Check constraints:
   "group_standings_draws_check" CHECK (draws >= 0)
   "group_standings_losses_check" CHECK (losses >= 0)
   "group_standings_points_check" CHECK (points >= 0)
   "group_standings_wins_check" CHECK (wins >= 0)
```

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION disallow_team_name_update() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
            if(NEW.team <> OLD.team)
            /*tell the user to not change team names*/

    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER tr_disallow_team_name_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF team ON group_standings 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE disallow_team_name_update();
```

Comment: ... Your code isn't supposed to return the old team name, it's supposed to throw an error if you try to change it at all.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You're correct, how do I change it to display an error instead of the old team? And the error that I am getting is psql:tables.sql:48: ERROR:  missing "THEN" at end of SQL expression
LINE 5:   RETURN OLD.team;

Comment: ... I'd say that error is telling you exactly what's wrong with the current statement.  The error actually belongs as part of the question.  I'm actually surprised that it's not complaining about the double-equals (`==`), as SQL uses context-sensitive single-equals for comparisons.  Presumably you could use the in-equality operator(s) to check if the names don't match, although I don't know how to get PostrgeSQL to throw an exception deliberately.

Comment: Paste your function into your question.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: PostgreSQL uses the cryptically named `raise exception` to [raise an exception](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html).

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I added it, sorry stack overflow is being weird to me right now. But anyway can you help me complete my function? This is the last thing I need to do for my assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL can use `raise exception` to, um, raise exceptions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION disallow_team_name_update() 
RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
    BEGIN
        if(NEW.team <> OLD.team) then
            raise exception 'Invalid update.'
            using hint = 'Changes to team name are not allowed.';
        end if;

    END
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You surely don't want to disallow changes to the team name on *insert*. (PostgreSQL won't let you do it anyway.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_disallow_team_name_update 
BEFORE UPDATE OF team ON group_standings 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE disallow_team_name_update();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Are you still online to answer another quick question?